# Getting Internal Server Error 500 in Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, postman, multipartform-data

[image]I know there are a lot of threads regarding this and i did go through them and also looked into the same Retrofit POST example,but i'm not sure what am i doing wrong in this,lemme know if any

```
    @Multipart
@POST("api/customerdetail")
Call<Array> addUser(@Part("CustomerName") String CustomerName, @Part("CustomerId") String CustomerId, @Part("UserId") String UserId, @Part("VehicleCompanyName") String VehicleCompanyName, @Part("VehicleModelType")String VehicleModelType, @Part("VehicleNumber")String VehicleNumber, @Part("Location")String Location);
```

//METHOD USED TO CALL

```
private void simpleMethod() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://endpoint.net/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    GetDataService service = retrofit.create(GetDataService.class);
    Call<Array> arrayListCall = service.addUser("Peter Jenkins", UUID.randomUUID().toString(),"user2","AUDI","R3","BVZ-009","-55,-93.23"); arrayListCall.enqueue(new Callback<Array>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Array> call, Response<Array> response) {
        Log.e("RESPONSE",response.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Array> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("ERROR",t.toString());
    } }); }
```

Works like a Charm in Postman,and uploading an image is not necessary,atleast from the api end

[image: POSTMAN OUTPUT]

Any inputs would be deeply appreciated

Comment: something wrong on the server side.

Comment: @Raghunandan its fine in Postman

Comment: are you missing any header? i see one  Header i npostman Headers(1) in screen shot

Comment: @Raghunandan Nope haven't selected any headers in postman as well,like i said gives 200OK as shown in the image

Comment: i don't see any thing wrong with the retrofit code. i would recheck the headers or params required for your api call

Comment: just 1 question why Call<Array>?

Comment: @Raghunandan the response is supposed to be a array,but i don't think that would make any difference,i could change if you'd like and let you know

Comment: it should be something like `Call<List<T>>`

Comment: In postman you're sending an image file too. But you didn't do so in the code.

Comment: @rafid059 It depends upon what your response is going to be

Comment: @rafid059 its not necessary,there's no null check as such and would do a 200

Comment: Yes of course. But I suggested that based on the response I'm seeing

Comment: @Venky did you recheck the Headers tab in postman. the snap shot says Headers(1) so you do have a header in postman

Comment: @Raghunandan Added the image for the headers section

Comment: literally anything could be going wrong here. The only thing that can clear things up is checking the server logs to see what caused the 500 error. We can only guess

Comment: you could try adding  `@Headers("Content-Type:application/json")`

Comment: @Raghunandan But its not application/json,its formdata

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes, and i'm out of guesses at this point,need fresh eyes to guess

Comment: @Venky i looked at the snap shot and suggested the same. I would recheck the header and other params required for your api call and also check the server if everything is alright. As far as the code posted i would change to Call<List<pojo>> instead of array. apart from that i don't see anything wrong

Comment: @Raghunandan Neither my request nor my response is a List

Comment: @Venky din't you say it 's a  Array. you would be using a pojo for your json response right.

Comment: no you don't need fresh eyes to guess, you need to check the server logs

Comment: @Raghunandan all right my api won't be returning anything now,what should i put in cal then ??

Comment: @Venky `Call<Void>`

Comment: @Raghunandan Nope,thats not working either,this is just so freaking tiresome,spent a whole day for a POST call